# LCM of $n$ consecutive natural numbers

Tags: divisibility, least-common-multiple

Is there an efficient way to calculate the least common multiple of $n$ consecutive natural numbers? For example, suppose $a = 3$ and $b = 5$, and you need to find the LCM of $(3,4,5)$. Then the LCM of $3,4$ and $5$ is $60$. Is there an efficient way to do this for arbitrary $a$ and $b (a\leq b)$ that is more efficient than the naive approach$?$

Edit: What if I know the LCM of (1,2,3,4,..a) and the LCM of (1,2,3,..b). Is it possible to get the LCM of (a,a+1,..b) ?

Comment: Hmm, don't think so.  a and a+1 will have entirely different sets of prime factors so you are saving no time.  The is that if p|a the p will not divide any a+n where n < p, and if n > p then p will divide a+p.  But I don't think that really helps us with efficiency even if we did formulate it.

Comment: All I know is that $e=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[\large^n]{\text{LCM}[1,2,3,\ldots,n]}$.

Answer (score 1):

## $$\text{lcm}{\left\{1,2,3,...,N\right\}}=\prod_{p\in\text{prime}}{p^{\lfloor\log_pn\rfloor}}$$

For example, $\text{lcm}\{1,2,3,...,40\}=5342931457063200$

Answer (score 0):

A very interesting trick to find $LCM$,though its not exactly the same as your question.It does not deal with consecutive set of numbers.-

Let the numbers are-$(8,12).$

Steps:-

1.Find their $GCD$-Here it is $4.$

2.Now divide any of the given numbers by the $GCD$.Let us divide $8$ by $4$ here.It is equal to $2$.

3.Now,multiply it by the other number.Here it is $2*12=24$.It's your LCM.

Comment: Are $8$ and $12$ consecutive?

Comment: @egreg-Consecutive ones can be solved similarly..

Comment: The question is to find $\lcm(a, a+1, ..., b)$. In your example, the question asks for $\lcm(8, 9, ..., 12)$, not $\lcm(8, 12)$.

Comment: @tatan The OP knows it; the question is finding an *efficient* way.

Comment: @egreg-I think there's no such way...efficient enough....

Comment: In case of (8,12), you need to find the LCM of (8,9,10,11,12). your answer is wrong I guess.

Comment: Your answer is irrelevant to the problem, because $\text{lcm}(a,b)=\frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}$ only works for two numbers; for more numbers the formula becomes complicated and inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

To find the $\text{lcm}$ of the first $n$ natural numbers, we can use the relation
$n-1=\sum_{k=2}^{n}{e^{2i\pi Q}}$ and solve for $Q$ using numerical methods. This ends up getting quite tricky. We need to find the zeroes of the function 
$U(Q)=\sqrt{\left(\sum_{k=2}^n{\cos{\frac{2\pi Q}{k}}}\right)^2+\left(\sum_{k=2}^n{\sin{\frac{2\pi Q}{k}}}\right)^2}+1-n$. Finding the first root after $Q=0$ is quite difficult because the function is non-differential at many points. In fact, interpolation is no use either because the function oscillates at a rate approximately proportional to simply searching over $\mathbb Z$. That said, we can still find the $\text{lcm}$ for small enough $n$ by searching the utility space linearly over $\mathbb Z$.

For example, to find the $\text{lcm}$ of $\{1,2,3, . . . 10\}$, we compute $U(Q)_{|n=10}$ starting at $Q=1$ and continue until $U(Q)_{|n=10}$ is close enough to $0$. Taking roughly $15$ms on my machine, the number $1154160$ is produced. This is one answer to your question on a way to compute the LCM using a root finding algorithm. However, while thinking of ways to restrict the search space of the algorithm, I discovered a closed form solution to the problem, which I will post as a separate answer.